# How to close issue via PR whose target is not the default branch

Tags: github

To close a issue in Github via a PR you just need to add a key phrase like:

`Closes #100`

in the body of your PR and as soon as PR is merged into the default branch Github automatically closes the issue.

We merge our PR into branches under a version number (say branch `2.0.0`). but the issue remains open until we merge it into the default branch (in our case `development`).

My question is how to setup the branch and/or PR so that after merging the PR into the (non-default) target branch, it closes the issue automatically.

Comment: Why not ask GitHub support?

Comment: @tadman Good point. I've asked for over 10 days, no answer yet

Comment: This isn't strictly a programming question that pertains to code, so I'd say it's off-topic here, so there's probably a better place to ask.

Comment: @tadman There are 22K questions on Jira. those also are not directly programming questions, but it is definitely a commonly used tools for programmers.

Comment: It's a grey zone, honestly.

Comment: For those interested, As per tours page, this website is for questions in: Specific programming problems, Software algorithms, Coding techniques and *Software development tools*.

Answer (score 1):

As the answer of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67449219/github-pr-linked-issue-does-not-gets-closed-when-non-default-branch-is-merged) question says, an Issue will only close if it's merged into the main branch. There is no such option to do what you said in your question.

> the referenced issue will automatically be closed when the PR is merged into the default branch

That's why in 4 years nobody could tell you how to do this.
I think that your question it's useful because such option should be available for cases like your one.

---

The only way right now is to do it manually.

1. Merge the Pull Request
2. Close the issue with the `close` button

**But** you could build an github action that does this automatically:

```yaml
name: AutoIssue

on: # This you can set it up as you want, I made it trigger on a commit
  push:
    branches: [ master ]

  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - name: Merge Pull Request
      uses: juliangruber/merge-pull-request-action@v1
      with:
        github-token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
        number: <NUM> # Enter here the pull request number you want to merge
        method: squash
    - name: Close Issue
      uses: peter-evans/close-issue@v1
      with:
        issue-number: <NUM> # Enter here the issue number you want close
        comment: Auto-closing issue
```

The only things you have to change are the `<NUM>` placeholders

Comment: The link isn't working for me. As a person who put a bounty on this question, I appreciate the factual answer about what GitHub does automatically. The bounty I put on, though, asks about any solution to this, not just GitHub's automatic behavior. For example, could you build an action that would do this? If so, how? Thanks for responding, though.

Comment: I changed the link and updated the answer

Comment: @Mixchange what do you think? It's Ok?

Comment: Sorry, this workflow file would have to be edited every time to work, which seems harder than closing the issue manually. It wouldn't work automatically for all PRs. Thank you for fixing the link and for taking time to think about it.

Comment: A better solution could be "close issue" on "merge" instead of "on commit" : "merge" and "close". But in both cases the file must be edited