# GitHub - PR linked issue does not gets closed when non-default branch is merged with main

Tags: github

I have `main` as default branch and `dev` as non-default.

I created one issue and one PR to merge from new `temp` branch to `dev` branch
In PR, I have mentioned `Resolves #1`.

When I merge PR to `dev` branch, the issue `#1` does not gets closed as it is non-default branch.

Then I using git commandline inside `main` branch, I did `git merge dev` so `dev` branch is merged to `main`.

In `main` branch commits, I can see the `Merge pull request ...` commit as well.

But the issue `#1` does not gets closed even as PR is indirectly merged to `main` (from `temp` to `dev` to `main`)

Any reasons for the bug ?

Update: -
When merging `dev` to `main` , next time I did not used `git merge dev` on `main` branch, but I created new PR to merge `dev` to `main`.

And it closes the issue.

Why I worked while `merging with PR` and not when `git merge` is used ?

Comment: Where did you write the `Resolves #1`? In the description? Commit message? Comment?

Comment: In PR template...

Comment: I'm not sure why this is tagged with [tag:git] when it's exclusively a [tag:github] thing...

Comment: @torek. Agree, the tag git isn't needed and only confusing

Comment: I'm having a similar issue with a workaround to this, where I manually link the issues to be closed. Asked about it here: https://github.community/t/issues-which-a-linked-pr-is-supposed-to-close-does-not-close/230879

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is by design and not a bug

> When you merge a linked pull request into the **default** branch of a repository, its linked issue is automatically closed

And

> Note: The special keywords in a pull request description are interpreted when the pull request targets the repository's **default** branch. However, if the PR's base is **any other** branch, then these keywords **are ignored**, no links are created and merging the PR has no effect on the issues. If you want to link a pull request to an issue using a keyword, the PR must be on the default branch.

From
https://docs.github.com/en/github/managing-your-work-on-github/linking-a-pull-request-to-an-issue

*PS:  I have emailed GitHub support also for this in the past. Unfortunately is hasn't changed (yet)*

Comment: I got your point & understood the issue. But what should I do in such cases, manually mark the issues as closed ? Also if yes, there would be no use using automated kanban with reviews as project template and normal manual kanban would work ???

Comment: You could add the `Resolves #xxx` to the commit description.

Comment: I used to add `Resolves #xxx` in pull requests of features but it seems I have to add that in pull request of `merging dev to prod` ... correct ?

Comment: I feel so silly that I missed this. Thank you for this answer, I can sleep easily tonight.

Comment: Such a pity, especially if you use a pretty common practice, where you merge feature branches into a dev branch which is then later merged into the main (default) branch.